# Covert XYZ data to 2D raster

Tags: coordinate-system, 3d, 3d-analyst, geometry-conversion

I have a data from **terrestrial scanning** (3D) projected to 2D plane but still in XYZ format available here: http://ulozto.cz/xYkfywxY/xyz-to-2drst-txt.

Finally, my data are all on same plane, but every point has its XYZ information. I would like to **export the XYZ point shapefile to raster file in 2D where 1 point in .shp = 1 pixel** (pixel size not important for a while).

Please, any idea how to do that? I can use ArcGIS 10, R, ERDAS or some other software?

I found some information here: http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/39771 but they finish with raster interpolation and I want the raster information in format: point = pixel, no point = NoData.

Every advice is really welcome ! [XYZ point data in ArcScene representing two trees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKRwj.png) 
[image]

Comment: Do you want a DEM of the point cloud? Why not use something like [las2dem](http://rapidlasso.com/lastools/las2dem/)?

Comment: Your point data does not have equal intervals, which is necessary for building a raster without interpolation.

Comment: @Barbarossa, I will check it